# Is pan-project a word?

Tags: academia

In order to refer to something across all the sub-projects or areas of the project. 
What else could be one-word or an efficient way of saying, "You are going to work pan-project"?

Comment: Welcome to SE! Have you thought of any other terms that you've rejected?

Comment: Other not so elegant sentences, like "You going to work in all parts of project" or "all departments of project".

Comment: "Pan-project" is a technically legal construction, and would generally be understood, but it's not particularly idiomatic.  "Cross-project" is probably better (as are several terms we can't think of right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**cross-project**

[From M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross)

cross: extending over or treating several groups, conditions, or classes

- Christmas has become a *cross-cultural* secular holiday.
- These tests are *cross-curricular*. Teachers in all subjects need to be preparing their students for them.

So you might say: You'll be assigned *cross-project*.